# How do I remove the default localizations from a Phonegap/Cordova project?

Tags: xcode, cordova

I've just had a Phonegap/Cordova iPhone app approved for the app store but noticed it claims to be available in a bunch of other languages including Northern Sami. I've found the list of languages in xcode under localizations and tried deleting them but if I restart xcode they re-appear.

I've also tried deleting lproj folders in the resources folders but that doesn't help either.

I'm at a loss to what to do next so any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is a step by step guide of how I do it. (Order matters)

First go to the `Resources` folder in the Phonegap project. Within this folder there are several folders ending in `*.lproj`. Delete all of them except for `en.lproj` (Assuming your language is english).

[image: Resources folder]

Even though you deleted those files from your hard drive they're still linked in Xcode. Open up your `*.xcodeproj` and delete all of the folders from the side bar once again.

[image: Xcode]

Normally this should suffice, but if you're still having problems go to the app's project tab (rather than target) and under info you can find and remove all the current localisations.

[image: Xcode localisations]

Oh and btw if this still isn't enough you can look at the details of your app's binary in iTunesConnect to verify if it worked before releasing the app.

[image: iTC]

Comment: Thanks for this. Is there a way to automate this with a hook?

Comment: @pauloya i ended up writing a bash script hook that did the following. 1) delete all the non-english .lproj directories. 2) for 'de', 'es', and 'se', use sed and a specific regex to remove all one-line matches from the .pbxproj file. i can't say this will work for sure because i haven't yet submitted the updated app back to the app store.